# codepen code does not transfer well into visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, codepen

[This is the code](https://codepen.io/miguel-a-lopez/pen/WNyQQyW?editors=0010)

It seems the Javascript file is the one not loading on my webpage.

I have made sure the script js link is in the right place in the html document.

```js
(document).ready(function () {
  // typing animation
  (function ($) {
    $.fn.writeText = function (content) {
      var contentArray = content.split(""),
        current = 0,
        elem = this;
      setInterval(function () {
        if (current < contentArray.length) {
          elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
        }
      }, 80);
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

i added a snippet of js file because stackoverflow wont let me link my codepen without some code.

Comment: what does the error say? Do you have JQuery loaded on the machine? Is the script running after the page loads or before? Try moving inline js to the botton of the document.

Comment: you can use the Developer tools to inspect what HTML page Codepen generates. BTW I'm getting epileptic of the flashy scrolling